# How to group limited data based in multiple parameters in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet containing all responses to the questionnaire from multiple branches. It is like an audit where I have to answer OK or NOK, and if it's NOK I can indicate later that this fault has been corrected.

So the problem comes when I want to represent this data. The sheet contains ALL historic responses. It can be more than one answer for the same question. So I want to group by question per question category and per branch, in this order, and limit to show only the latest answer.

[image: data]

This is [an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ke8iwzXqhTlEgWm--OuO9Q1wOfoiHiEJ1bjrsauI5lU/edit?usp=sharing) of the data: in the DATA sheet there are all the responses and in the DESIRED RESULT sheet is the data I would like to obtain to show in the reports.

I tried with QUERY formula, but I am not able to group by multiple parameters, and maintain the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

```
=query(DATA!$A$1:$F;"select A,B,C, max(D), max(E), max(F) where A is not null group by A,B,C ";1)
```